# Disable Login in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.2, I have added `has_login` field in the `users` table.

Where do I add logic to prevent user logging in if `has_login` is value 0 in the `users` table? I use AuthController.php for authentication and `use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` without using `login()` / `authenticate()` functions in AuthController.hp file. Login work fine.

Comment: This logic should be in Authenticate.php inside Middleware folder.

Comment: @MarkoMilivojevic What the difference between Authenticate.php inside Middleware folder and AuthController.php in the controller?

Comment: Because every request goes through that middleware. You can see $routeMiddleware in kernel.php.

Comment: @MarkoMilivojevic Please add Answer how to add this logic in `Authenticate.php`  By the way I did not use `login()` in AuthController.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally tend to do this in the middleware, but you can also do it outside of that.

Here's a middleware example:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RequireHasLogin
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check())
        {
            if (!Auth::guard($guard)->user()->has_login)
            {
                Auth::logout();
                if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson())
                {
                    return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
                }
                return redirect()->guest('/auth/login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Though I think some people do this too:

```
Auth::guard()->attempt(["email" => $email, "password" => $password, "has_login" => true])
```

Comment: Do I need to specify `RequireHasLogin` class somewhere?

Comment: Yes. You add it to `$routeMiddleware` inside of `app/Http/Kernel.php`

Answer (score 0):

This should point you in the right direction -

https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#authenticating-users